# Is there a web-based generic metric monitoring service?

Tags: performance, deployment, monitoring, metrics

First of all... I'm not looking for New Relic :-)

I'm looking for something very **similar to [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org)** but hosted, and accessible (at least for pushing data) via an HTTP API.  I want to monitor some **custom metrics on a web-application** and I'm looking for nice graphs, historical data, ease of setup and obviously the ability to use custom metrics that I'll measure and report myself.  I'll be using it to monitor aspects of a NodeJS app, but the source of the data shouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Try [AlertGrid](http://alert-grid.com). It has extremely simple API (via HTTP), with [only one method](http://alert-grid.com/documentation/) which is used to push any custom data. Then you build rules in a nice and simple editor to handle the incoming data (e.g. if metric1>10 and metric2 not in ['a','b','c'] then send email to X and sms to Y) or handle situations when expected event did not occur at all within a timeframe (e.g. when no data received from X for 15 minutes, then email to Y, sms to Z). It can also automatically draw simple graphs from the received data (for integer and float fields). Everything is web-based.

Unlike Nagios, AlertGrid is extremely simple to use and integrate, and requires no installation. If you know how to make a http request, then in 5 minutes you have a working solution ([examples](http://alert-grid.com/documentation/integration-code-samples/) and [wrapper classes](http://alert-grid.com/documentation/wrapper-classes/) are available). I'm on the dev team, so if you had any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Looks like a sweet product that I will likely use, but I'm looking more for historical analysis and aggregation of numbers changing over time (min, max, avg, graphs, ...)  Think Google analytics, but for system state instead of visitation stats.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) or write plugin for Munin.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com/). I think it would check the boxes on all of your requirements. We've been using it to set up dashboards for a number of services at Mobify and so far it's been a pleasure to use.

I've recently released a NodeJS library that might be helpful: [datadog-metrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datadog-metrics).

Here's some example code:

```js
var metrics = require('datadog-metrics');
metrics.init({ host: 'myhost', prefix: 'myapp.' });

function collectMemoryStats() {
    var memUsage = process.memoryUsage();
    metrics.gauge('memory.rss', memUsage.rss);
    metrics.gauge('memory.heapTotal', memUsage.heapTotal);
    metrics.gauge('memory.heapUsed', memUsage.heapUsed);
};

setInterval(collectMemoryStats, 5000);
```